# How to make compas's arrow heading to certain point?

Tags: c#, .net, geolocation, maui, compass-geolocation

I have this code:

```
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;

namespace MauiApp1;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    double kaliningradlongitude = 54.70934095352097;
    double kaliningradlatitude = 20.469516749819515;

    double tokyolongitude = 35.76242245296096;
    double tokyolatitude = 139.261582628989;


    private void ToggleCompass()
    {
        if (Compass.Default.IsSupported)
        {
            if (!Compass.Default.IsMonitoring)
            {
                // Turn on compass
                Compass.Default.ReadingChanged += Compass_ReadingChanged;
                Compass.Default.Start(SensorSpeed.UI);
            }
            else
            {
                // Turn off compass
                Compass.Default.Stop();
                Compass.Default.ReadingChanged -= Compass_ReadingChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Compass_ReadingChanged(object sender, CompassChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update UI Label with compass state
        this.text.Text = $"{e.Reading} + {this.arrow.Rotation}";
        this.arrow.RotateTo(e.Reading.HeadingMagneticNorth - RadianToDegree(Bearing(tokyolongitude, tokyolatitude, kaliningradlongitude, kaliningradlatitude)));
    }
    public static double Bearing(double pt1long, double pt1lat, double pt2long, double pt2lat)
    {
        double x = Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(pt1lat)) * Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(pt2lat)) - Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(pt1lat)) * Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(pt2lat)) * Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(pt2long - pt1long));
        double y = Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(pt2long - pt1long)) * Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(pt2lat));

        // Math.Atan2 can return negative value, 0 <= output value < 2*PI expected 
        return (Math.Atan2(y, x) + Math.PI * 2) % (Math.PI * 2);
    }
    private double RadianToDegree(double angle)
    {
        return angle * (180.0 / Math.PI);
    }

    public static double DegreesToRadians(double angle)
    {
        return angle * Math.PI / 180.0d;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleCompass();
    }
}
```

I have the most western point = Kaliningrad, and the most eastern point = Tokyo. What do I want? I want to make compas's arrow heading to Tokyo (as if I'm in Kaliningrad) depending where I look. Let's imagine that Tokyo is on East and compas's arrow must head to East, even if I look at South or North and etc.
Now my compas's arrow is buggy and don't work properly.

Comment: You already asked this and were pointed towards an existing question explaining how to do this.   What was wrong with that answer?

Comment: also, "is buggy and don't work properly" is not a helpful description of the problem.  What specifically is wrong?  Do your calculations produce the correct result?  Or is the problem in your implementation of the Compass UI (which you don't show)?

Comment: @Jason Yeah. I have found the bearing through Math. but when I use bearing as value to rotate compas's arrow it's static, but must be dynamic.

Comment: @Jason 
As UI I use simple arrow image, that I rotate via ".rotateTo". Calculations are work properly. They give me bearing. But arrow is static whenever I look.

Comment: if the problem is that your UI is not updating, then it would help a great deal if you posted the relevant markup and code.  Have you tried using `MainThread` to for the UI update to run on the UI thread?

Comment: Could you provide some more relevant code so that I can reproduce the situation you described.